# merging two sorted linked lists into one linked list in python

Tags: python, list, linked-list, sorting

here is my code:

```
def merge_lists(head1, head2):
    if head1 is None and head2 is None:
        return None
    if head1 is None:
        return head2
    if head2 is None:
        return head1
    if head1.value < head2.value:
        temp = head1
    else:
        temp = head2
    while head1 != None and head2 != None:
        if head1.value < head2.value:
            temp.next = head1
            head1 = head1.next
        else:
            temp.next = head2
            head2 = head2.next
    if head1 is None:
        temp.next = head2
    else:
        temp.next = head1
    return temp
    pass
```

the problem here is stucked in the infinite loop.can any one tell me what the problem is

the examples are:

```
 assert [] == merge_lists([],[])
 assert [1,2,3] == merge_lists([1,2,3], [])
 assert [1,2,3] == merge_lists([], [1,2,3])
 assert [1,1,2,2,3,3,4,5] == merge_lists([1,2,3], [1,2,3,4,5])
```

Comment: Python native list members don't have `head` and `value` attributes. Your examples can't run as-is.

Comment: i didnot get your point can you tell me more clearly @mtrw

Comment: @srikarthikmodukuri We don't know what 'head1' and 'head2' refer to - you have not included them in the code sample. Please do.

Comment: @srikarthikmodukuri - if `head1 = [1,2,3]` then accessing `head1.value` will give error `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'value'`. So with native python list this program will never work. Are you passing some different type of list to function `merge_lists`??

Comment: here head1 means one sorted list and head2 means another sorted list @selllikesybok

Comment: can you help me to write this code?. thanks in advance @anuragal

Comment: here's code example: [`mergesort-linkedlist.py`](https://gist.github.com/zed/5651186)

Comment: Where's the rest of your code for a linked-list class? You mentioned something about node objects in another comment.

Comment: It seems very confusing to call a Linked List head

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem with the current code is that it causes a side-effect of the temp node's next *before* it navigates to the next node from the current node. This is problematic when the current temp node *is* the current node.

That is, imagine this case:

```
temp = N
temp.next = N  # which means N.next = N
N = N.next     # but from above N = (N.next = N) -> N = N
```

There is a corrected version, with some other updates:

```
def merge_lists(head1, head2):
    if head1 is None:
        return head2
    if head2 is None:
        return head1

    # create dummy node to avoid additional checks in loop
    s = t = node() 
    while not (head1 is None or head2 is None):
        if head1.value < head2.value:
            # remember current low-node
            c = head1
            # follow ->next
            head1 = head1.next
        else:
            # remember current low-node
            c = head2
            # follow ->next
            head2 = head2.next

        # only mutate the node AFTER we have followed ->next
        t.next = c          
        # and make sure we also advance the temp
        t = t.next

    t.next = head1 or head2

    # return tail of dummy node
    return s.next
```

Comment: thanks for telling me i understood the concept and code well.thanks

Comment: Can you explain the dummy node concept? I did indeed have many more lines and control flow.

Answer (score 11):

Recursive algorithm for merging two sorted linked lists

```
def merge_lists(h1, h2):
    if h1 is None:
        return h2
    if h2 is None:
        return h1

    if (h1.value < h2.value):
        h1.next = merge_lists(h1.next, h2)
        return h1
    else:
        h2.next = merge_lists(h2.next, h1)
        return h2
```

Comment: Can you specify the time and space complexity of this solution?

Answer (score 0):

**Complete code:-**

Definition of "Node" class for every single node of Linked List.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None
```

Definition of "linkedlist" Class.

```
class linkedlist:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
```

Definition of "Merge" function.

The parameters "ll1" and "ll2" are the head of the two linked list.

```
def merge_lists(ll1, ll2):
    if ll1 is None:
        return ll2
    if ll2 is None:
        return ll1

    if (ll1.data < ll2.data):
        ll1.next = merge_lists(ll1.next, ll2)
        return ll1
    else:
        ll2.next = merge_lists(ll2.next, ll1)
        return ll2
```

Taking input into list.

```
l1 = []
try:
    l1 = list(map(int,input().strip().split()))
except EOFError:
    pass
l2 = []
try:
    l2 = list(map(int,input().strip().split()))
except EOFError:
    pass
```

Creating linked list namely **ll1** and **ll2** from the input list values.

```
ll1 = linkedlist()
ll1.head = Node(l1[0])
itr1 = ll1.head
for i in range(1,n1):
    temp = Node(l1[i])
    itr1.next = temp
    itr1 = itr1.next

ll2 = linkedlist()
ll2.head = Node(l2[0])
itr2 = ll2.head
for i in range(1,n2):
    temp = Node(l2[i])
    itr2.next = temp
    itr2 = itr2.next
```

Merging two sorted linked list using merge function by passing the head of the two linked list

```
itr = merge(ll1.head,ll2.head)
```

"merge" function returns an iterator itself whose values are printed as:

```
while itr != None:
    print(itr.data,end=" ")
    itr = itr.next
```

**Custom input and output:-**

Input

1

4

1 3 5 7

4

2 4 6 12

Output

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 12

Comment: Hi and thanks for your feedback. However, explaining how this can solve the OP question and why his solution didn't work is more valuable.

Comment: @WaLinke Thanks for pointing out, I have updated the solution of merging two linked list with explanation.

Answer (score 0):

To me, it was more pythonic to **convert a LinkedList to list and back**.
I also implemented print function to output the LinkedList, which helps for testing and debugging.

```
def ln_to_list(ln):
    tmp = ln
    lst = [ln.val]
    while tmp.next:
        tmp = tmp.next
        lst.append(tmp.val)
    return lst

def print_ln(ln):
    return '->'.join([str(el) for el in ln_to_list(ln)])
    
def ln_from_list(lst):
    if not lst or len(lst) == 0: 
        return None
    head = ListNode(lst[0])
    tmp = head
    for i in lst[1:]:
        tmp.next = ListNode(i)
        tmp = tmp.next
    return head
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all let me make clear, it is the problem of the leet code as I mentioned so here I was just trying to answer the problem, the logic itself.

Time complexity: O(n+m) where n is len(l1) and m is len(l2) as we are traversing only once.

Space complexity: O(1), we don't create any new object and just reconnect each other.

```
 class ListNode:
     def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
        self.val = val
        self.next = next
 class Solution:
     def mergeTwoLists(self, l1, l2):
        head = res = ListNode()
    
        while l1 and l2:
            if l1.val <= l2.val:
                res.next = l1
                l1 = l1.next
            else:
                res.next = l2
                l2 = l2.next
            res = res.next
        if l1: res.next = l1
        if l2: res.next = l2
        return(head.next)
```

#create a new linkedlist which is used to store the result

#here I have used two refereces to the same list since I should return the root of the list

#head will be used during the process and res will be returned. –

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thanks for providing this algorithm along with its time and space complexity. Can you explain how it works? Why have a `Solution` class instead of just having a `mergeTwoLists` function? What's the difference between `head` and `res`, and why do they both refer to the same object?

Comment: Actually let me make clear, it is the problem of the leet code as I mentioned so here I was just trying to answer the problem, the logic itself.

Comment: #create a new linkedlist which is used to store the result 
#here I have used two refereces to the same list since I should return the root of the list
#head will be used during the process and res will be returned.

Comment: I hope you get it.

Comment: Thanks for responding! Since you have added details about _your own_ answer, you should edit your answer to include those details. (You can always edit your own posts.) They will be much easier to read compared to having them in comments.

Comment: Ok, I wil do that.