# how to merge two sorted linked lists in python

Tags: python, list, merge, linked-list, sorting

i tried so many algorithms to merge the linked lists...

```
def merge_lists(head1,head2):
    if head1 is None and head2 is None:
        return None
    elif head1 is None:
        return head2
    elif head2 is None:
        return head1
    if head1.value <= head2.value:
        result = head1
    else:
        result = head2
    while head1 != None or head2 != None:
        if head1 != None and head2 != None:
            if head1.value <= head2.value:
                result.next = head1
                head1 = head1.next
            else:
                result.next = head2
                head2 = head2.next
        elif(head1!=None):
            result.next = head1
        elif(head2!=None):
            result.next = head2
    return result
    pass
```

for eg., the test cases are

```
assert [] == merge_lists([],[])
assert [1,2,3] == merge_lists([1,2,3], [])
assert [1,2,3] == merge_lists([], [1,2,3])
assert [1,1,2,2,3,3,4,5] == merge_lists([1,2,3], [1,2,3,4,5])
assert [1,10] == merge_lists([10], [1])
assert [1,2,4,5,6,7] == merge_lists([1,2,5], [4,6,7])
```

can any one give me the code to pass these test cases ? thanks in advance.

Comment: Post the code (algorithms) you have tried, and tell us why do you think they don't work. Maybe the `list#extend()` and `sorted()` functions would be helpful.

Comment: Google for `list.extend`

Comment: Where is the "linked" in these "linked lists"?

Comment: I hope `pass` wasn't actually one of the algorithms you tried.

Comment: here i used linked lists it means extend method will not support linked lists.can you give me the code please thanks in advance @thefourtheye

Comment: `[1,2,3]` is a list. It's Python notation.

Comment: actually its converted to nodes i didnot wrote the code here but can you help me please? thanks in advance

Comment: We're not going to do your homework for you. You haven't even given us enough context for us to give you the code even if we wanted to.

Comment: @srikarthikmodukuri - you are asking same question again and again with improper data. [link to your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22507197/merging-two-sorted-linked-lists-into-one-linked-list-in-python)

Comment: @user2357112 Why not?! I thought that's what Stack Overflow was - a homework and work replacement!

Comment: `"can any one give me the code to pass these test cases?"` - Are we supposed to believe that you wrote those test cases, but couldn't even attempt to implement the algorithm in question??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This operation is just doing the "merge" step of a [Merge Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#) and can be done in `O(l1+l2)` time.

The general premise is to iterate over both (already sorted) lists at the same time, but only advance the list with the lowest head value, while using the advanced value in the resulting output. The operation is complete when both source lists are exhausted.

Here is some [pseudo-code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Top-down_implementation_using_lists) (courtesy of the Wikipedia) and shouldn't be too hard to translate for a linked list data-type. When implementing it for a linked list a new list can either be created or one of the lists can be destructively modified.

```
function merge(left, right)
    // receive the left and right sublist as arguments.
    // 'result' variable for the merged result of two sublists.
    var list result
    // assign the element of the sublists to 'result' variable until there is no element to merge. 
    while length(left) > 0 or length(right) > 0
        if length(left) > 0 and length(right) > 0
           // compare the first two element, which is the small one, of each two sublists.
            if first(left) <= first(right)
                // the small element is copied to 'result' variable.
                // delete the copied one(a first element) in the sublist.
                append first(left) to result
                left = rest(left)
            else
                // same operation as the above(in the right sublist).
                append first(right) to result
                right = rest(right)
        else if length(left) > 0
            // copy all of remaining elements from the sublist to 'result' variable, 
            // when there is no more element to compare with.
            append first(left) to result
            left = rest(left)
        else if length(right) > 0
            // same operation as the above(in the right sublist).
            append first(right) to result
            right = rest(right)
    end while
    // return the result of the merged sublists(or completed one, finally).
    // the length of the left and right sublists will grow bigger and bigger, after the next call of this function.
    return result
```

Comment: how to calculate length of a linked list ?

Comment: @srikarthikmodukuri `length(l) > 0` means "is a non-empty linked list" (e.g. the current node, `l`, is valid/not-None)

Comment: @srikarthikmodukuri Btw, the code in your other question that I just saw, you never update the `temp` node in the loop so it never really "appends".

Comment: based on your algorithm i wrote the code but it went to infinite loop.can you help me please? thanks in advance

Comment: @srikarthikmodukuri The infinite loop is caused by the mutations to the `temp` node. The `next` property of the corresponding l1/l2 node is being set *before* it is traversed.

Comment: @srikarthikmodukuri Since this information is more relevant to your other question, I posted an answer there.

Comment: i didnot get your point can you tell me more clearly?

Answer (score 0):

```
def merge_lists(x,y):
    comb = []
    comb += x + y
    comb.sort()
    return comb
```