# merging two sorted linked lists python

Tags: python, data-structures, linked-list

I have implemented a function to merge sorted linked lists but the last node isn't merging. if I set current.next to l2, I'm getting infinite loop. if I remove that it works but without the last node attached to the new list. What am I doing wrong?

```
def merge(self,l1,l2):
    if l1.val < l2.val:
        current = l1
        l2 = l2
    else:
        current = l2
        l2 = l1
    while(current != None):
        if current.next == None and l2 != None:
            #current.next = l2 infinite loop if I include this
        elif current.next.val > l2.val:
            temp = current.next
            current.next = l2
            l2 = temp
        current = current.next

    self.printList(current)
```

List1: `5 7 16`

list2: `2 4 6 8 10`

Expected `2 4 5 6 7 8 10 16`, Current Result `2 4 5 6 7 8 10`

Answer (score 0):

taken from the accepted solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22507197/merging-two-sorted-linked-lists-into-one-linked-list-in-python) this algorithm fixes yours:

```
def merge_lists(head1, head2):
if head1 is None:
    return head2
if head2 is None:
    return head1

# create dummy node to avoid additional checks in loop
s = t = node() 
while not (head1 is None or head2 is None):
    if head1.value < head2.value:
        # remember current low-node
        c = head1
        # follow ->next
        head1 = head1.next
    else:
        # remember current low-node
        c = head2
        # follow ->next
        head2 = head2.next

    # only mutate the node AFTER we have followed ->next
    t.next = c          
    # and make sure we also advance the temp
    t = t.next

t.next = head1 or head2

# return tail of dummy node
return s.next
```

Answer (score 0):

I was missing checks on corner cases, here is a fix:

```
def merge(self,l1,l2):
    if l1.val < l2.val:
        current = l1
        l2 = l2
    else:
        current = l2
        l2 = l1
    while(current != None):
        if current.next == None and l2 != None:
            current.next = l2
            l2 = None

        elif current.next != None and l2 != None and current.next.val > l2.val:
            temp = current.next
            current.next = l2
            l2 = temp
        current = current.next
```